# How to automatically permanently ban IP addresses?

Tags: debian, iptables, fail2ban, ip-address

Currently I have been using iptables on a new Debian server running Asterisk.

Every day I have been checking auth.log for IP addresses and manually doing `iptables -A INPUT -s IPA.DRE.SS.0/24 -j DROP`

I was initially doing just IP addresses but many hits were coming from similar IP addresses so /24 has been working better, I have used /16 a couple of times.

Already I have hundreds of iptables entries and this is getting out of control! I know there must be an easier way to do this.

fail2ban has been recommended to me but it seems it blocks IPs only temporarily after a certain # of attempts.

The two main intrusion attempts I see are using false usernames and random ports.

Is it possible to, if an attempt is made to login with any username I am not currently using, to automatically permanently block the IP address? Same with ports that are not in use?

I also see a lot like this:

```
Did not receive identification string from (malicious IP) port 48334
```

I'd like to ban those IPs too.

I won't automatically block incorrect login attempts as if I fat-finger the password that could lock me out. But perhaps a permanent ban on an IP after 3 attempts will suffice.

Can I do this with iptables? I haven't found anything regarding "permanent bans" that work like this, it seems it just works more in the moment.

I'd more or less like to accomplish what I've been doing manually; permanently blocking IP ranges after a single wrong username login, a single wrong port connection, or 3 incorrect login attempts (with correct username). I'm hoping this will prevent auth.log from getting spammed.

Comment: check out http://www.honeyd.org/configuration.php ..... maybe the solution is to use a "tarpit" .... the undesirable connection is not refused, but becomes very, very, very slow and in the end does not lead anywhere

Comment: @Christopher Only a small number of IP addresses are going to be connecting to my machine (hundreds maximum). It's a private Asterisk VoIP server.

Comment: @Christopher The only caveat is I don't know the IPs and some are changing constantly. Numerically the amount of possible connections is relatively small but I can't do a block-first approach sadly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fail2ban` can be configured for permanent bans by setting `bantine` to `-1`

In `jail.conf`

```
bantime = -1
```

These will be lost on a reboot, but that's not necessarily a bad thing because so many attempts will be transient from pwned home machines in a botnet...

If you want persistence, then https://arno0x0x.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/fail2ban-permanent-persistent-bans/ may give some guidance.

Essentially modifying the `fail2ban` config to create a persistent configuration file of all the banned IPs, and have iptables load this list on reboot...

So if you check your default `jail.conf` you may find the default action is `iptables-multiport`.  This corresponds to the configuration file `/etc/fail2ban/ction.d/iptables-multiport.conf`

We can add the following entries:

```
[Definition]
# Option:  actionstart
# Notes.:  command executed once at the start of Fail2Ban.
# Values:  CMD
#
actionstart = iptables -N fail2ban-<name>
              iptables -A fail2ban-<name> -j RETURN
              iptables -I <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j fail2ban-<name>
          cat /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans | awk '/^fail2ban-<name>/ {print $2}' \
          | while read IP; do iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s $IP -j <blocktype>; done

# Option:  actionstop
# Notes.:  command executed once at the end of Fail2Ban
# Values:  CMD
#
actionstop = iptables -D <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j fail2ban-<name>
             iptables -F fail2ban-<name>
             iptables -X fail2ban-<name>

# Option:  actioncheck
# Notes.:  command executed once before each actionban command
# Values:  CMD
#
actioncheck = iptables -n -L <chain> | grep -q 'fail2ban-<name>[ \t]'

# Option:  actionban
# Notes.:  command executed when banning an IP. Take care that the
#          command is executed with Fail2Ban user rights.
# Tags:    See jail.conf(5) man page
# Values:  CMD
#
actionban = iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>
        echo "fail2ban-<name> <ip>" >> /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans
```

Now, when `fail2ban` flags an entry it will add a line to `/etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans`  (via the `actionban` configuration).  When `fail2ban` starts up it calls `actionstart` which reads this file and builds the `iptables` rules necessary.

Of course, `fail2ban` needs restarting after any of the configuration files are changed.

All credit to "arno0x0x" and his wordpress site for this recipe.

Comment: Could the settings be saved, much like iptables-save, and restored on reboot somewhat like iptables-restore?

Comment: This gets more complicated and involves modifying the `fail2ban` config to create a persistent configuration file of all the banned IPs, and have iptables load this list on reboot..... https://arno0x0x.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/fail2ban-permanent-persistent-bans/ explains the details.  I'm loathe to cut'n'paste that information because it'd be plagarism, and I've not tested it myself.